# Vertical padding in tabularx cells without using tabular or table

Tags: tabularx

The **problem** is that there is not enough space between the rules on top of each cell and its content.

The use of `\arraystretch` doesn't work in my example because I don't put my `tabularx` inside a `tabular` or `table` environment.

I am not sure if this is something about my use of `\parbox` or `\mutlirow`. That is why I keept it in my MWE here.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mrwidth}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytext}{And then it happened… a door opened to a world…
    rushing through the phone line like heroin through an addict's veins, an
    electronic pulse is sent out, a refuge from the day-to-day incompetencies is
    sought… a board is found.}

\setlength{\mrwidth}{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}  % <-- doesn't work here

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}*{\parbox{\mrwidth}{\mytext}}
        &b&c&d&e\\\cline{2-5}
    &\parbox{\mrwidth}{\mytext}
        &c&d&e\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `The use of \arraystretch doesn't work in my example because I don't put my tabularx inside a tabular or table environment.` ??? `\arraystretch` works with `tabularx` in the same way as it works with other `tabular` variants` it does not need to be in a surrounding `table` or `tabular`

Comment: How important is it to you that all five columns have exactly the same width? Please advise.

Comment: @buhtz -- What does "a solution against that rule" mean? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico It is important. But I am interested in your solution.

Comment: As I don't know what "a solution against that rule" might mean, I'm not in a position to provide an answer. (That, and the fact the posting is currently closed a duplicate, meaning that no new answers can be posted...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\rewnewcommand\araystretch{1.1}` is not cure for all cases ... your table is quit unusual, so it doesn't help in placing of text in `multirow` cells. In your case you need another aproach, for example use of `gapedcells` from package `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytext}{And then it happened ... a door opened to a world ...
    rushing through the phone line like heroin through an addict's veins, an
    electronic pulse is sent out, a refuge from the day-to-day incompetencies 
    is a board is found.}

\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{10}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\mytext}}
        &b&c&d&e\\\cline{2-5}
    &\mytext
        &c&d&e\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** The `\arraystretch` work as name implied, in any array environment, from `array`, `tabular` to even `tabu` (most of them are based on `array`). Regarding columns width in your table: if it is not necessary that all to have the same width, you can change it, for example with `>{\setlength\hsize{0.5\hsize}}X` (to make it narrower) or even in case, that in columns are cells with only one line text use `l` column type. With this you can increase width of other `X` columns and obtain nicer text formatting in it.

Already now you can obtain slightly better text formatting, if you reduce font size and its shape:

```
{\sffamily\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
...
\end{tabularx}
}
```

[image]

Beside this is worth consider package `ragged2e` and its macro `\RaggedRight`. With it text is not justified anymore, but hyphenation still works. With it you obtain the following result:

[image]

(considered \sffamily\small fonts). Changes in above MWE are: added `\usepackage{ragged2e}` in preamble and in table:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{10}*{\parbox{\mrwidth}{\RaggedRight\mytext}}
        &b&c&d&e\\\cline{2-5}
    &\RaggedRight\mytext
        &c&d&e\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

**Addendum:**
In all efforts to make good answers for you I forgot an very basic `mutirow` futures: defining it width with `linewidth`. This introduce `p{\linewidth}` type of cell, where the text is automatically broken in multi line text. So, the `parbox` seems to be not necessary (on this remind me Bernard answer, where this is used), however the hyphenation seems to be different. Difference is observable, if you futher decrease font size to `footnotesize`:

[image]

In above picture the first column is without use of `\parbox`. With its ˛use, the text shape in this column is the same as in the secon.

Comment: I see we had the same basic idea, with some differing details. Did you try with `cellspace`?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with it yet. I know, that in some circumstances it make less troubles as `makecell`. I need to read its manual again. In the first look i obtain (probably wrong) impression, that it is complicated ...

Answer (score 1):

With the `makecell` package and its`\setcellgapes` command, it's easy, and you can have a simpler code. No `\parbox` with width computation needed.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe, a4paper}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytext}{And then it happened… a door opened to a world…
    rushing through the phone line like heroin through an addict's veins, an
    electronic pulse is sent out, a refuge from the day-to-day incompetencies is
    sought… a board is found.}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\mytext}
        &b&c&d&e\\\cline{2-5}
    & \mytext
        &c&d&e\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot on defining multirow width with `linewidth`. Very elegant and far more simple solution than mine (+1)!